# Unresolved identifier NavigationButton error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11

I'm new to swiftUI and just trying to figure out the basics. I'm simply trying to create a new view and a button that will move to it.

When I use the code below, an error appears: "Use of unresolved identifier 'NavigationButton'" despite that being generated by Xcode.

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {

    var body: some View{
        NavigationView {
            NavigationButton(destination: NextView()) {
                Text("Navigate 1")}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`NavigationButton` changed to `NavigationLink` for a while now. So replace it and use it.

Answer (score 3):

`NavigationLink` replace `NavigationButton`, The code below is update for WWDC 2019 [Introducing SwiftUI: Building Your First App](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/204/)

```
struct RoomCell: View {
    let room: Room

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: RoomDetail(room: room)) {
            Image(room.thumbnailName)
                .cornerRadius(8)
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(room.name)
                Text("\(room.capacity) people")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
        }
    }
}
```