# Creating nav link error in Swift UI/ Xcode

Tags: swiftui, navigationview, swiftui-navigationlink

I am trying to add a Navigation view that goes from my ContentView to my list items inside of my SectionView and then goes to my DetailView...i'm getting an error and i'm not sure why? im trying to nav link `SelectionView( codeName: "Y")`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                
                NavigationLink("Y", destination:codeName.
                               (model:  .codeName))
                
                List (models) { model in
                    SelectionView(codeName: model.codeName)
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        
#if DEBUG
        struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
            static var previews: some View {
                ContentView()
                    .previewLayout(.device)
                    .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
                    .previewDevice("iPhone 13 Pro Max")
            }
        }
#endif
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error? But anyway `codeName.(model:  .codeName))` doesn't seem right, you might have an extra period in there

Comment: Where does a guy named 'models' come from?  SelectionView?  Where does it come from?

Comment: models is my var which I added in my data

Answer (score 0):

The destination also should be a view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0 ..< 5) { item in
                    
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: Text("Destination \(item)"),
                        label: {
                            Text("Hello, world!  \(item)")
                                .padding()
                        })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, So I was following a youtube video and they used a NavigationButton but I guess that has been depreciated. This was the code that he used

Comment: NavigationView {
List (developers){Developer in 

NavigationButton:
(destination: ContentDetail
(codeName:
developer.codeName)) {
Contentrow(codeName:
developer
.codeName)

Comment: In my code, I changed the values from developer, to model. I changed the ContentDetail to DetailView, I changed the ContentRow to SectionView  ....everything else has stayed the same but now I cant figure out how to use the NavigationLink rather than the Navigation Button that he used

Comment: https://youtu.be/Pfw7zWxchQc?t=1060 This is the Video and im trying to do the same thing except with Navlink

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615514/unresolved-identifier-navigationbutton-error

Comment: Instead I will suggest better tutorial , If you are gonna follow alone https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu